# Merge Python arrays in a loop?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, beautifulsoup

I'm currently getting an output of A,A,B,B instead of A,B,A,B.

I really want to associate the values of each table header with each table data element (like a dictionary).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

courseCode = "IFB104"
page = requests.get("https://www.qut.edu.au/study/unit?unitCode=" +     courseCode)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all(class_='table assessment-item')

numOfTables = 0
tableDataArray = []

for tbl in table:
    numOfTables = numOfTables + 1 
    tableDataArray += [tbl.find_all('th'),tbl.find_all('td')]
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the table looks like and what your desired output would be?

Comment: It currently prints `3
[[<th>Name</th>, <th>Description</th>, <th>Weighting</th>, <th>Due date</th>, <th>Internal or external</th>, <th>Group or individual</th>, <th>Relates to learning outcomes</th>], [<td>#3: Quiz/Test</td>, <td>Weekly quizzes. Each week in the lectures you will be introducing to computing principles used to solve technical problems. Your understanding of these techniques will be tested via weekly online quizzes and tests</td>, <td>25&amp;percnt;</td>, <td>Throughout semester</td>, <td>Internal</td>, <td>Individual</td>, <td>1,2</td>]]`

Comment: It prints all of the <th> tags from this table (one of tables three in the entire HTML page), and then all of the <td> tags). I want to make a dictionary (I originally said array, but a dictionary is better) to associate each <th> with each <td>. That way, I can call the assessment's name, and get returned "#3: Quiz/Test", or weighing and get "25%".

Comment: I dont really understand, what the problem is, but did u try: `tableDataArray += [...] ?`

Comment: Wait, I've figured it out. The for tbl in tables is iterating through each table (3) and printing everything. I need to also iterate through each <th> and <td> as well and add them to a dictionary?

Comment: I also need to append each table to the tableDataArray, because right now it's only printing the last loop (erasing the array each time, I suppose), thanks Maurice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need to use dict, instead of list:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

courseCode = "IFB104"
page = requests.get("https://www.qut.edu.au/study/unit?unitCode=" + courseCode)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all(class_='table assessment-item')

numOfTables = 0
tableFormatted1 = []
tableFormatted2 = {}

for tbl in table:
    numOfTables = numOfTables + 1
    keys = tbl.find_all('th')
    values = tbl.find_all('td')
    new_data = dict(zip(keys, values))

    # Method 1
    tableFormatted1.append(new_data)

    # Method 2
    for k, v in new_data.items():
        if k in tableFormatted2:
            tableFormatted2[k].append(v)
        else:
            tableFormatted2[k] = [v]

print('List of dictionaries')
print(tableFormatted1)
print('')

print('Dictionary with list')
print(tableFormatted2)
```

Edited:

Each iteration of `tbl` is overwriting the iteration already done. So, it is necessary to change the structure. I've just provided two methods.

Comment: Almost perfect! Except I realised I need to do it for all three tables, not just one. My original post had a mistake where I typed `tableDataArray =...` instead of `+=`. It's supposed to iterate through 3 tables.... breaking it down at the <th>, <td> level.

Comment: But there is a problem. The keys are the same (`name` can be `Portfolio`, `Examination (written)` or `Quiz/Test`). Do you need a key with a list for all of the values?

Comment: Or is better to have a list, containing a dict with all the parameters?

Comment: I don't want to sound demanding, but I don't mind if they have the same value so long as I can extract them individually – as in, a new dictionary for as many tables as there are, or any other method of separation. It's for a web interface that takes many course codes, so there's different numbers of assessments (therefore different numbers of tables).

Comment: A list, containing a dict would work? First list item being the first assessment table dict?

Comment: I've just edited. It is showing two ways to solve it.